# yntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data when debugging enabled

Tags: json

guys - I have a problem, and there are quite a few people struggling to find the solution for this. The error above appears when I try to upload photos (jpg, png) directly into chat plugin. Chat plugin has another option which is 'Attach file' and it let's me to attach all files. On debug - we have received this error. I have read all articles related to this one but did not see anything with this specific error in debug. Please, I would be happy to hear if you have any thoughts... I have just run out of options regarding this issue.
[error shown in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BGhr.png)

Than kyou very much for any information

Comment: You'll probably need to be more specific to get a good answer. From your screenshot, it looks like you're using WordPress, but what chat plugin are you using? It would be helpful to include the response from the server and any errors in the apache logs if there are any.

Comment: Hi Mathew. Thank you. It was the PHP EXIF extension missing.  All ok with that nw:)